# Windows 8 project type performance differences

Tags: javascript, c++, performance, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++, C# and JavaScript on WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466303/c-c-sharp-and-javascript-on-winrt)

I am wanting to create an app for Windows 8 and am equally well versed in C++ and JavaScript. I was wondering what (if any) performance differences there would be between a JavaScript/HTML or C++/XAML. Do they both get compiled to the same source or is the JavaScript version interpreted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS runs in the Chakra javascript engine just like JS would in a browser app.  In general, the perf differences between the two environments for a lot of scenarios.  When you get down to specifics, then yes, you would see perf differences, but the majority of apps don't need to worry about them.  If you are doing hard core 1st person gaming, intense/heavy number brunching, etc. then you may need to look at C++ or .NET.