# What are the pros and cons of writing C#/Xaml vs. HTML/JavaScript WinRT applications in Windows8

Tags: c#, javascript, html, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am planning to develop a metro app which will contact a server and will download and preview images, PDF, audio and video files. I am confused whether to write it in C#/Xaml or in HTML/JavaScript.

I have a C#/Xaml background, what added advantages will i get developing the same in HTML/JavaScript and not in C#/Xaml?

Comment: Interesting question, but it doesn't really fit SO standards. I think it'll be closed as non constructive. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466303/c-c-sharp-and-javascript-on-winrt My humble opinion: just use C#+XAML as you already know it, and it has tons of advantages (better dev tools, strong typing...)

Answer (score 5):

I found an existing thread with several useful answers on this:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156361/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-using-xaml-c-or-html5-javascipt-for-metro-apps

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

There is a //Build/ 2013 recording of a session [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/2-192) that is exactly about strengths and weaknesses of each platform.